# В чем заключается отличие Яндекс Map Kit от Яндекс Карты API?

Tags: java, android, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты, yandexmapkit

Стоит задача: добавить карты Яндекс в мобильное приложение. В ходе поиска информации выяснил, что это можно сделать двумя способами: Яндекс Map Kit и Яндекс Карты API. В чем состоит их отличие? Что из этого лучше использовать для мобильного приложения на Android? Работаю в Android Studio, пишу на Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

яндекс карты API - веб апи (для сайтов чаще всего)

yandex mapkit - sdk для приложений, есть конкретно под Android, в данном случае он и требуется.

Comment: Разве кит не похоронили?

Comment: ну он относительно живой, то месяцами ничего, то выпустят новую версию. Последнее обновление было в марте.

Comment: Map Kit, который доступен на github'е, уже много лет deprecated - там исправляют только критические проблемы для новых устройств. Но, может, новый появится.